# Is is possible to check which level an sstable belongs to when using LeveledCompactionStrategy?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

When using `LeveledCompactionStrategy` sstables are organized in "levels". Is it possible to check which level a file belongs to?

Background: I have a bunch of tombstones that I eventually will have compacted. I'm curious to see how many levels down these tombstones are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `tools/bin/sstablemetadata`

Usage: sstablemetadata < sstable filenames >